# My laptop bluetooth does not pair with hearing aids

Tags: bluetooth

My Windows 8.1 laptop with bluetooth sees my hearing aid devices, but won't pair, even using a dongle.  I was able to pair with my Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Hearing Aids to pair with a device, you need the App provided by the Hearing Aid manufacturer installed and then also to set up assistive devices in the Device settings. Most Smart Phones can install the App and have the Assistive Device settings. Your Windows 8 computer may not have the Assistive Device settings.